# Compare two sheets and highlight differences: Runtime Error 457 - This key is already associated with an element of this collection

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I want to compare two sheets and highlight differences.

This code gives me

> Runtime error - 457 - This key is already associated with an element of this collection.

It highlights below lines when I debug

```vb
Dic(Dn.Value).Add .Range("A5").Offset(, ac).Value, _
  Intersect(Dn.EntireRow, .Range("A5").Offset(, ac).EntireColumn)
```

I have read many posts related to this.

```vb
Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, ac As Long
Dim Rng2 As Range, Dic As Object, Q As Variant
    
Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
With wbComparison.Sheets(1)
    Set Rng = .Range("A5", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each Dn In Rng
        If Not Dic.exists(Dn.Value) Then
            Set Dic(Dn.Value) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If
        For ac = 1 To 31
            If Not IsEmpty(.Range("A5").Offset(, ac).Value) Then
                Dic(Dn.Value).Add .Range("A5").Offset(, ac).Value, _
                  Intersect(Dn.EntireRow, .Range("A5").Offset(, ac).EntireColumn)
            End If
        Next ac
    Next Dn
End With
    
With wbComparison.Sheets(2)
    Set Rng2 = .Range("A5", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each Dn In Rng2
        For ac = 1 To 31
            If Dic.exists(Dn.Value) Then
                If Dic(Dn.Value).exists(.Range("A5").Offset(, ac).Value) Then
                    Q = UCase(Dic(Dn.Value).Item(.Range("A5").Offset(, ac).Value))
                    If Not Q = UCase(Intersect(Dn.EntireRow, .Range("A5").Offset(, ac).EntireColumn)) Then
                        Intersect(Dn.EntireRow, .Range("A5").Offset(, ac).EntireColumn).Interiro.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next ac
    Next Dn
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition a dictionary cannot have the same key.

When you add to you `Dic` variable : `Dic(Dn.Value).Add` you add the same `Dn.Value` twice this is why you have this error.

Try to use another structure like an array or a list to store your values.

Comment: Thank you... but I still didn't understand.. like I said.. I am not a pro.. I can just add a macro and run the files. if possible... can you amend this row by adding an array or a list for me?... Sorry.. but I need help to run this code smoothly.